# Self-assigned IP address ethernet issue

Tags: network, ethernet

I'm trying to connect my MBP15 2017 to my router using a Dell DA300 hub (Wifi works well). I keep getting the self-assigned IP issue.

What I've already tried:

- rebooting
- rebooting the router
- using a different port on the router
- using a different port on the MBP
- resetting NVRAM
- resetting SMC
- giving the MBP a DHCP client ID
- creating a new location (then it doesn't connect at all)
- disabling SIP
- disabling Lulu firewall
- disabling pfctl

I haven't tried using it with another computer as I only have this one available. Do you have any other ideas what may help?

Comment: Is the router set up to run DHCP?

Comment: Yes, and a NAS connected to it runs well. I'm connected to the same router via WiFi right now without any issues.

Comment: Is the adapter actually supported?  If you statically assign it an IP address (and other parameters) in the proper range, does it work?

Comment: It's not officially supported. I know that some people use it with their Macs and are happy but I don't know whether they use ethernet. I'm not sure I can set up a static IP with my router, looks like it only has these options for WAN, and LAN can only have DHCP.

Comment: No, a static IP address on the *client*.

Comment: I tried it and either it didn't work or I did something wrong. The connection status was green but I had no internet access.

Comment: Sounds like the Ethernet port on that hub is not supported by macOS.